# ResultSet is only returning one row while database has more rows java/sql

Tags: java, sql

the problem i am facing is that my result set is only returning one row value while there are three.
and i could not found where the problem is:

```
  public void eventInfo() throws SQLException
    {
     openConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps1=null;

    String query1="select * from events";

    try {
        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }





            EventData e= new EventData();
            e.edata.clear();
            Events obj = new Events();

    ResultSet s=ps1.executeQuery();
    int i=0;

            System.out.println(s);

    if(s.next())
    {
//                        obj.setId(s.getInt("id"));
//          obj.setTitle(s.getString("title"));
//          obj.setDescription(s.getString("description"));
//          
//          obj.setType(s.getString("type"));
//          obj.setOrganization(s.getString("organization"));
 //         obj.setPlace(s.getString("place"));
 //         obj.setTime(s.getString("time"));
 //         obj.setDate(s.getString("date"));
 //         obj.setRepetetion(s.getString("repetetion"));
 //         obj.setParticipants(s.getInt("participants"));
 //         obj.setLimit(s.getInt("elimit"));

                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(s.getString("title"));
                    i++;

                 //   e.edata.add(obj);


    }


    if(con!=null)
    {
        con.close();
    }

    }
```

the database tables like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA7l1.png)

the output looks like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBuao.png)

can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

It should not surprise you that

```
if(s.next())
```

is not a loop but rather a condition. If you want to continuously access the result set you have to use a loop

```
while (s.next())
```

Comment: Thank you so much...i just ignored that... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
while (s.next()) {...}
```

...should do it for you. This will iterate through all rows.

Comment: Thank sir ... i got the result now